# Can I use DC20V/6.75A instead DC20V/6.5A Power Adapter

Tags: power-supply

Can I use DC20V/6.75A instead DC20V/6.5A Power Adapter for my VisionTek VT4000 - Dual Display 4K USB 3.0 & C Docking Station?

Comment: Thought experiment: The supply in your house is typically capable of 50 to 100 A. What happens if you plug in a device that only needs 0.5 A?

Answer (score 1):

If it both stabilized output power supply will be no problem.  Not stabilized power supplies rated with output voltage with current, close to maximum, at lower load output voltage will be higher and may cause damage. Also the primary power supply may need overcurrent protection. Best to use original PS, using another should take more thing in consideration.  More info needed to  answering.

Comment: These questions come in so often that we have created a canonical answer, and we just send anyone who asks to that answer. See @awjlogan's comment.